# Virtual device not showing up in Android Studio

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, android-emulator, windows-7-x64

I am a total newbie in Android Studio programming.
When I click the Run button to run my program, my virtual device doesn't show up in Select Deployment Target and I get the following error:

```
18:08:32 error: Invalid argument: cannot open transport registration       
socketpair
18:08:32 could not read ok from ADB Server
18:08:32 * failed to start daemon *
18:08:32 error: cannot connect to daemon
18:08:32 'C:\Users\samarc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform- 
tools\adb.exe,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
```

What should I do? This seems to be the only thing that is stopping me from programming in Android Studio. Any and all help will be appreciated. I use Android Studio 2.2.3 and Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 2):

Just check there might be an existing adb process running in your task manager. Just kill the process and run the 'adb start-server' command.

Other Method:
Close android studio and the emulator and check in your task manager for another adb process and kill it if one exists.
If you have done it open Android studio again and first of all start the emulator and if it is running then your project.

You can even do it manually:
adb kill-server
adb start-server

Hope it helps

Comment: There isn't any existing adb process running in my Task Manager. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Do you have a virtual device running?
If not try run it before you click start. 
Which virtual device did you try?

Comment: And what do you mean by your third paragraph (I am a total newbie) by the way ?

Comment: I used virtual device "Nexus 6P API 24". What do you mean by "before you click start"?

Comment: the third paragraph ist about type the commands in the console (cmd)/command line interface.
- Windows button - search "cmd" and type the two commands in. first kill then start

I mean before you hit the run button.

Comment: So finally did it work?
How did you run it because I am also getting the same issue? I created the Nexus 6 virtual device but it does not show up in the devices list.

Answer (score 0):

One may need to delete *.lock file from the Android main folder location and then at the subfolder as follow Android InstalledPath.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_26.avd
If you are not able to delete the file and then try deleting the corresponding *.exe process from the task manager and then run the Android studio again and then AVD Manager. Select the virtual device (which shows available in play store)